# Highchart: addSeries vs. chart.options.series

Tags: javascript

I have inherited a project that is using Highcharts.

The previous dev used the `.addSeries` method to add all of the series to each chart that was being rendered. From what I've read of Highcharts, it seems like `.addSeries` is really for adding data dynamically.

The data that is being used to populate the charts are coming from an AJAX request. The old dev's approach was to get the data, render the chart, and then add a series using `.addSeries`. I was thinking that it might be better to update `options.series` and then pass the whole thing along to `new Highcharts.Chart()` for rendering, taking the `.addSeries` out of the equation.

However, since I'm new with Highcharts, I was hoping to get some feedback on what the better method would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on a good path, though your question suggests you may simply be looking for preference over a strict right/wrong answer.

From what I've seen, unless you have interactions on the page that would trigger a need to update your chart after it's been drawn, the benefit to using `addSerie` would be to add some visual flare. Using `addSerie`, your charts will visually draw themselves in front of the visitor - vs them already being drawn. (I believe HighCharts demo site has some good examples of this.)

I also recently inherited a HighCharts project and am generating a new `Highcharts.Chart()` using dynamic data by parsing the AJAXed data on the fly. The good news is that all of the charts still have nice visual flare (flare is important) since they don't draw until the AJAXed data is fully loaded. This snippet illustrates how I've been loading dynamic charts, parsing the JSON data on the fly:

```
   $(function () {
        var visitsChart;
        $(document).ready( function() {
            $.getJSON('/json-data-url', function(json){        
                var visitsChart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'visitsContainer',
                        type: 'spline',
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Test Widget'
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: 'Speed',
                        data: [parseInt(json.visits)],
                    }],
                ...
                });     
            });   
        });
    });
```

I won't lie ... I had a few minutes of hair pulling when I got started but now I wish I had more time to work with Highcharts as it's quite fun once you get on a roll. Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh, okay. Didn't realize it was responsible for that visual flare of the chart drawing itself. Definitely want to keep that in. And the little bit of benchmarking I've done has shown that using addSeries isn't adding too much of an overhead (I can be drawing up to 10 charts at a time) so I'll continue to use it. Thanks!